# InkWell call the AlertDialog

Tags: flutter, dart

I need the user to click on this "Inkwell", an "alertdialog" appears, I tried to do it on another screen, but when clicking the screen goes black.

```
InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, AppRoutes.helpScreen);
                  },
                  child: const Text(
                    "contact us",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xff05498A),
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      fontSize: 16,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: when black screen appear ?.while alert dialog clicking or navigate to new page.if navigate to new page .then you wrap the widget with scaffold widget

Comment: Can you give a bit more context? What is `AppRoutes.helpScreen` exactly? How does this widget look like?

Comment: But on your Inkwell your doing a Navigator.pushNamed as opposed to a showDialog unless you’ll be doing a fullScreenDialog. Will the dialog show on this screen or the next one?

Comment: the black screen appears when the user clicks "contact us".

Comment: AppRoutes.helpScreen: (context) => const ContactUsDialog(),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question and Comment:

Your widget CustomDialog widget Need to wrap with `Scaffold` widget or `material` Widget

**Use like this**

```
class ContactUsDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  const ContactUsDialog({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: TextButton(
        onPressed: () => showDialog<String>(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Contact us', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 75)),
            content: Text(
              "Please contact our team via email: contatcus@help.com.br",
            ),
          ),
        ),
        child: AlertDialog(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Instead of this**

```
class ContactUsDialogFailed extends StatelessWidget {
  const ContactUsDialogFailed({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
      onPressed: () => showDialog<String>(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
          title: Text(
            'Contact us',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 75),
          ),
          content: Text(
            "Please contact our team via email: contatcus@help.com.br",
          ),
        ),
      ),
      child: AlertDialog(),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

**SampleCode**[Dartpad you can check live](https://dartpad.dev/?id=22f362edb0035b90a1219fe1c2879c45)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: AppRoutes.home,
      routes: {
        "${AppRoutes.home}": (context) => Home(),
        "${AppRoutes.helpScreen}": (context) => ContactUsDialog(),
        "${AppRoutes.failed}": (context) => ContactUsDialogFailed(),
        "${AppRoutes.Page4}": (context) => Page4(),
      },
      title: _title,
      // home: ,
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("title")),
      body: const Center(
        child: MyStatelessWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 100,
          ),
          Container(
            height: 100,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, AppRoutes.helpScreen);
              },
              child: const Text(
                "Contact us Success",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xff05498A),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  fontSize: 16,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 100,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, AppRoutes.failed);
              },
              child: const Text(
                "Contact us Failed",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xff05498A),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  fontSize: 16,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page3 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Page3({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Material(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text("Failed"),
            InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                showDialog<String>(
                  context: context,
                  barrierDismissible: false,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
                    title: const Text('AlertDialog Title'),
                    content: const Text('AlertDialog description'),
                    actions: <Widget>[
                      TextButton(
                        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 'Cancel'),
                        child: const Text('Cancel'),
                      ),
                      TextButton(
                        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 'OK'),
                        child: const Text('OK'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
                // Navigator.pushNamed(context, AppRoutes.Page4);
              },
              child: const Text(
                "contact us",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xff05498A),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  fontSize: 16,
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page4 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Page4({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
        child: Text("Success with Scaffold"),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AppRoutes {
  static String helpScreen = "/help";
  static String failed = "/failed";
  static String Page4 = "/page4";
  static String home = "/";
}

class ContactUsDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  const ContactUsDialog({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: TextButton(
        onPressed: () => showDialog<String>(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Contact us'),
            content: Text(
              "Please contact our team via email: contatcus@help.com.br",
            ),
          ),
        ),
        child: AlertDialog(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ContactUsDialogFailed extends StatelessWidget {
  const ContactUsDialogFailed({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
      onPressed: () => showDialog<String>(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Contact us'),
          content: Text(
            "Please contact our team via email: contatcus@help.com.br",
          ),
        ),
      ),
      child: AlertDialog(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: When the user clicks on "contact us", first a blank screen appears and then the AlertDialog appears, and if you click outside the AlertDialog disappears and the screen is blank. How do I make the "Alert" stay on the same screen?

Comment: barrierDismissible: false, add in you showdialog method.https://dartpad.dev/?id=22f362edb0035b90a1219fe1c2879c45

Answer (score 2):

```
InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          // call this method
          showAlertDialog(context);
        },
        child: const Text(
          "contact us",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Color(0xff05498A),
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
            fontSize: 16,
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

**Create this Method..** and call InkWell onTap function

```
showAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {
    // set up the buttons
    Widget cancelButton = TextButton(
      child: Text("Cancel"),
      onPressed: () {},
    );
    Widget continueButton = TextButton(
      child: Text("Continue"),
      onPressed: () {
        //Navigator.push(
        //context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Page1()));
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, AppRoutes.helpScreen);
      },
    );

    // set up the AlertDialog
    AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
      title: Text("AlertDialog"),
      content: Text(
          "Would you like to continue learning how to use Flutter alerts?"),
      actions: [
        cancelButton,
        continueButton,
      ],
    );

    // show the dialog
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return alert;
      },
    );
  }
```

**Thank You...**

Answer (score 0):

more context is needed to give an accurate solution. like what is happening inside of "AppRoutes" widget ? did you make sure to register the AppRoutes widget in your main.dart routes?

- in your Navigator.pushNamed you are calling "AppRoutes" which is a non existing widget. replace it with

  **Navigator.pushNamed(ContactUsDialog.helpScreen);**

and in your "ContactUsDialog" Widget declare a const outside your build method

```
static const helpScreen = '/anyNameYouWant';
```

register it in your routes in main.dart like this

```
 routes: {
             ContactUsDialog.helpScreen : (ctx) => ContactUsDialog(),
   }
```

Comment: AppRoutes.helpScreen: (context) => const ContactUsDialog(),

Answer (score 0):

this was the screen I created, to be called by clicking on "contact us".

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ContactUsDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  const ContactUsDialog({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
      onPressed: () => showDialog<String>(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Contact us'),
          content: Text(
            "Please contact our team via email: contatcus@help.com.br",
          ),
        ),
      ),
      child: AlertDialog(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you think it is necessary to create a route and another screen for the "AlertDialog"?

Comment: How about amending original question?